# Schwinger and Source Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

As for Schwinger's book on source theory, it is quite terse and his arguments are difficult to follow. If anyone has understood the idea and implementation (mathematical) of source theory, can you provide a succinct mathematical account of the theory and detail whether or not it is actually an alternative to traditional techniques of QFT (read Feynman diagrams and canonical quantization).

Comment: related: [Source Theory - Alternative to QFT](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98694).

Comment: Saw that link. I didn't find the answer satisfactory. I would ideally like a short description mathematically of what source theory actually entails, or a different reference as asked (not Schwinger's own book in the subject).

Comment: As written, this is probably too broad. It might be more useful (to you and to the community) to change this to a [tag:resource-recommendations] by asking for alternative sources than Schwinger's book.